# Can i develop Windows 7 desktop apps using Windows 10?

Tags: wpf, windows-7, windows-10

Is it possible to develop desktop applications for Windows 7 using a machine running Windows 10? I am trying to use WPF for developing the app and have Visual Studio 2015 installed on my device.

I am aware that its not possible to develop Windows 8/10 stores apps on Windows 7 but am not sure if its possible the other way round?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can develop a backward compatible WPF app on Windows 10 as long as you don't run code that uses APIs introduced in Windows 10 when it runs on another version of Windows.

You can detect Windows version or better detect features to ensure your app will use the right API depending on the OS it runs.

Check the [System.Environment.OSVersion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion.aspx) API to detect Windows version

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is no reason why you couldn't do that.